# Do I need to subscribe to the redux store in Angular2?

Tags: angular, redux

Using a Redux store in a component I am taught to do the following:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.store.subscribe( () => {
        this.counter = this.store.getState().counter;
    });
}
```

Why can't I simply write `{{store.getState().counter}}` in my template. It works fine, even better, because the initial value is displayed.

1. Is there a reason to explicitly subscribe or does it angular2 for you behind     the scenes?
2. If I need to subscribe, how do I display the initial value?

**@dannyjolie**:

Thanks for trying to explain, but your assumption is not true. In the following snippet I changed the template back from the subscribed class variables to the store and it keeps working. (see [Github](https://github.com/z-bit/a2_redux_todo.git) for full project)

```
@Component({
    selector: "todo-list",
    directives: [Todo],
    pipes: [VisibleTodosPipe],
    template: `<div>
        <ul>
            <todo
                *ngFor="#todo of store.getState().todos | visibleTodos: store.getState().filter"
                [completed]="todo.completed"
                [id]="todo.id"
            >
                {{todo.text}}
            </todo>
        </ul>
    </div>`
})
export class TodoList {
    constructor(
        @Inject('AppStore')
        public store: AppStore
    ){
        this.unsubscribe = this.store.subscribe(() => {
            let state = this.store.getState();
            this.currentFilter = state.filter;
            this.todos = state.todos;
        });
    }

    private ngOnDestroy(){
        this.unsubscribe(); //remove listener
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Redux with Angular2, but I'm quite sure this is because of the Redux state's immutability. For a primitive like counter, which I guess is an integer, no problems. But consider an object. If your template makes use of a value further down in the state tree you will probably have a big problem seeing updated values.

`{{store.getState().counterObject.value}}` will bind you Angular model to whatever `counterObject.value` is at runtime. In your counterObject reducer, *a completely new `counter` object will be created*, but you model will still point at the old memory reference to counterObject. That object will not change. To overcome this, you must subscribe to changes in the store, and bind `this.counter` to the current value.

To sum it up with pseudo-ish code:

```
// Initial counter state, counter is stored in e.g. memory location 1
counter = {
 foo: 'bar',
 value: 0
}

// Bind this object directly
{{this.store.getState().counter.value}} // Points at memory location 1

// Update counter with a reducer
counter = Object.assign({}, counter, {value: 1}) // Creates a new object, memory location 2

// Angular fails to update, because it's still pointing at the first counter object stored in memory location 1
```

Comment: First thanks for going through the trouble finding an explanation!

Comment: That's really interesting! I think I have to try the Angular2/Redux combo myself, just to experiment with it. When you say you are taught to set `this.counter` in the `store.subscribe` callback, what is your information source? And what does your `todos` reducer look like?

Comment: Here is the [code](https://github.com/z-bit/a2_redux_todo.git) and taught refers to [Gerard Sans](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-redux-1cf18af27e6e#.qrrhlqow3). You will find the reducer in **src/todo/todoActions.ts**. It seems to me that there are really two valid ways to get the data.